# Storybook relative path stories

Tags: javascript, node.js, storybook

I'm trying to make my `ui-components` stories and code match in hierarchy. For example if I add another sub button component, I would like it to be reflected under `Buttons` in the storybook. Each component has a self contained story located with it and is being imported into one story (`stories/index.stories.js`) like so:

```
const req = require.context("../ui-components", true, /.stories\.js$/);
function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

This is my folder structure

```
- ui-components
-- Button
--- Nested_Button
---- index.js
---- stories.js
-- index.js
-- stories.js
....
- stories
-- index.stories.js
```

The story name will nest using slashes, so is there a way I can write my component stories like this?

```
const ButtonStories = storiesOf(`${THIS_MODULE_PATH_RELATIVE_TO_UI_COMPONENTS_DIR}`, module).add(
  "A basic button",
  () => <Button>Basic Button</Button>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have ended up doing is in my component stories using the __dirname variable as a story name.

This wasn't working before due to Storybook using a default config so I added a custom `webpack.config.js` to get the correct paths.

```
const path = require("path");

// Export a function. Accept the base config as the only param.
module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
  // `mode` has a value of 'DEVELOPMENT' or 'PRODUCTION'
  // You can change the configuration based on that.
  // 'PRODUCTION' is used when building the static version of storybook.

  // Make whatever fine-grained changes you need
  config.node = {
    __dirname: true,
    __filename: true
  };

  // Return the altered config
  return config;
};
```